# Implement an interface with the same name in Java

Tags: java, interface, queue

I am recreating basic data structures as an assignment. I have an interface called Queue and I have to implement the same data structure with the same name (both are in different packages) I tried doing something like this but it gives a warning

```
Queue is a raw type. References to generic type Queue<E> should be parameterized
```

This is my code

```
public class Queue implements uo.mp2021.util.collections.Queue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's it a Queue of?

Anything?

```
public class Queue<E> implements uo.mp2021.util.collections.Queue<E>
```

Something?

```
public class Queue implements uo.mp2021.util.collections.Queue<Something>
```

The point is that the interface is generic, so you need to decide whether you're providing a generic implementation, or a specific implementation.